# Can flex tape be used to repair an HVAC condensate drain pan?

Tags: hvac

I have an attic unit that was recently getting a lot of water in the pan under the full unit.  The plastic condensate drain pan has a crack in it.  The HVAC tech said it will cost $800 to replace the pan.

A friend mentioned that I might want to try and patch the pan first.  He suggested using flex tape.  He's used the liquid and tape on boats and it's worked really well. (this friend is an MEP engineer and knows a decent amount about HVAC systems) We discussed using the tape because the liquid could be messy.  One problem is that it's hard to tell how far the crack goes under the coil.

I'm curious about a few things:

1. Is there something better than flex tape for this?
2. How involved is it for a tech to replace the pan?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: For any repair it is important to make sure the surface is very clean.  Imagine most of the 800$ is the labour of removal and replacement of the pan, but I could be mistaken and they do charge 750 just for the pan.  Pan should be easier to seal than a boat, very little movement once it is done.

Comment: Lifting the air handler in the attic may be a real bugger a lot would be on how large it is , are the ducts hard or flex and is there room to lift it up. 
The cost sounds high but everything is going through the roof these days, I would expect the pan to be 100 or less. A wider shot of the area would help give the answers to all the questions I asked , I am not one for bandaid fixes as it may work for a wile then fail at a bad time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We managed to pull out the whole coil and pan.  My friend held it while I got under it and patched the pan.  We used Flex Tape on the top and bottom.  It's bone dry now :)

This is just to get me through the summer and I'll order a new pan and replace when it's cooler.

[image]